# Avoiding to put logic on view to display element on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given that is always better to avoid logic on view.

Let say I have a button that I want to show only to admins.

I'd do in my view:

```
<% if current_user.admin_role? %>
button
<% end %>
```

Is there any way to remove the if statement from view and reach the same result? In a rails way, possibly without javascript?

Comment: Yes, use a presenter. There is a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?autoplay=true) on the topic that might help you get you started.

Comment: Ok heard about it but never looked into it. I will now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment:

> Yes, use a presenter. There is a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?autoplay=true) on the topic that might help you get you started.

I wanted to add that, IMO, once you get the hang of the presenter pattern, it is really super. My views now have essentially no logic. And, I never, ever access any models or model instances in my view.

In fact, my presenters aren't allowed to interact with models, either. Neither are my controllers.

I have a special class called 'managers' that are responsible for all interactions with models. (Also, I'm pretty stingy about letting my models interact with one another unless it's through AR assocations. No `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my part of the woods.) I believe some people sometimes call these sorts of objects "services". I have services, too. But that's a different topic.

My presenters only know about arrays, hashes, strings, integers, and things like that. They don't know a bit about models.

And since my controllers delegate everything to managers and presenters, all of the actions in my controllers look like this:

```
def show
  do_action_with_presentation
end
```

or like this:

```
def show
  do_action_and_render_result
end
```

That's it! Controllers have enough responsibility without asking them to do a lot of interesting stuff.

The separation allows me a lot of liberty in moving pieces around without blowing stuff up (which I'm good at).

Comment: +1000 for presenters. Rails is great but still missing some tools, Presenters or Decorators are among them.

Comment: The railscast is enough to do what I wanted to and clean up my views. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I had a look at decorators too. Is it correct to say that decorators and presenters do the same thing? So I should choose between one or another? Or are there cases when is convenient to use both?

Comment: I suppose it depends on how one implements decorators and/or presenters. And, TBH, I'm not that familiar with decorators. But, [here's](http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/31-exhibit-vs-presenter) an interesting read on the topic. My presenters have no knowledge whatsoever of the model layer and so are quite distinct (I think, but don't know) from decorators. Between my managers and presenters, I just haven't found myself needing to explore decorators at all.

Comment: It sounds like a very interesting feature. Yet everything that is inside a rails application is server sided. And to me using a model record inside a view is still something that is not exposed to the outer world... (I am a bit teasing here but it's because I am still shortsighted in terms of ROR programming as of now..)

Comment: @Maxence - I'm not sure it's entirely accurate to say that everything inside a rails application is server sided. I have plenty of javascript in my apps that is entirely client side and interacts with the server solely via APIs. (I stopped using js.erb ages ago.) Also, personally, my reason for separating layers within my rails apps isn't really about what the 'outer world' sees or knows. It's about [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and making smaller components that are easier to develop, test, reuse, etc. and insulating components from change.

Comment: @Catmal - In the last few weeks, I've found myself using decorators quite a lot (for the first time ever). Based on my early experience and the way I'm using them, decorators and presenters are *very different* animals. Decorators, in my world, are very closely coupled to models while presenters are entirely decoupled from models. Presenters intimately involved in the presentation layer while decorators are not. Anyway, interesting stuff.